# Need help to translate a Notion progress bar into Google sheets

Tags: unicode, google-sheets-formula

I saw a progress bar on Notion that looks really nice, and I wonder can someone help me translate this into something I can apply in Google Sheets?

Thank ahead!

The original function for notion is from https://linmi.cc/2429.html

As you can see, this progress bar with heart emoji is very cute: [heart progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrzER.png)

And after searching on internet, the best I can do on Google sheets is like this: =REPT(char(9825),3/14*100)&char(10)&round((3/14*100),2)&"%"

3 is the "current page" and 14 is the "total page."
[Google sheet progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVSoj.png)

The Unicode for the white heart is char(9825) and for the black heart is char(9829).

Thanks for any help! And you are more than welcome to share the amazing work you've done with Google sheets. I just notice it's such a powerful self-planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Assuming that your value is in B2 and total number is in C2:

```
=rept(char(9829),int(B2/C2*10))&rept(char(9825),10-int(B2/C2*10))
```

[image]

This formula takes value and checks what fraction of total it is. (let's say it's 12 of 100. This makes 0.12. If I have 10 hearts, I multiply this value by ten and convert it to integer (cut the value after comma. So instead of 1.2 of heart I have one heart). So I repeat this heart as many times as needed.

Then I concatenate and do the similar way with white hearts:
I take 10 and subtract the number of black hearts.

Comment: I just have one more follow-up question: is it possible to change the color of hearts? I add color code same as =SPARKLINE(B4:C4,{"charttype","bar";"color1",if(B4>C4,"#dd7e6b","a3bc9f");"color2",if(C4>B4,"#dd7e6b","a3bc9f")}), but it doesn't work here.

Comment: Only by changing font color.

Comment: Great to know. Thank you for your help!